# Estrutura de repetição while com problemas

Tags: python, loop, while, idle-ide

Ele pergunta na primeira vez a operação desejada duas vezes depois funciona normal.

```
print("Calculadora\n")

print("1º Soma")

print("2º Subtração")

print("3º Multiplicação")

print("4º Divisão \n")

resposta = str(input("Qual operação você deseja usar?\n"))

while((resposta !='soma') or (resposta !='subtração') or (resposta !='multiplicação') or (resposta !='divisão')):

    print("Digite uma operação válida")
    resposta = str(input("Qual operação você deseja usar? \n"))

    if resposta == 'soma':
        n1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro valor "))
        n2 = int(input("Digite o segundo valor "))
        resultado = n1+n2
        print("A soma de", n1, "+", n2, "é", resultado)

    elif resposta =='subtração':    
        n1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro valor "))
        n2 = int(input("Digite o segundo valor "))
        resultado = n1-n2
        print("A subtração de", n1, "-", n2, "é", resultado)

    elif resposta =='multiplicação':
        n1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro valor "))
        n2 = int(input("Digite o segundo valor "))
        resultado = n1*n2
        print("A multiplicação de", n1, "*", n2, "é", resultado)

    elif resposta =='divisão':
        n1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro valor "))
        n2 = int(input("Digite o segundo valor "))
        resultado = n1/n2
        print("A divisão de", n1, "/", n2, "é", resultado)
```

Comment: Sim, você solicita a operação fora do laço de repetição e novamente logo no início do laço. Era esperado que solicitasse duas vezes. Aliás, a condição que colocou no `while` será sempre verdadeira, então seu programa entrará em loop infinito independente do valor informado.

Answer (score 1):

Tem um problema no seu código:

```
((resposta !='soma') or (resposta !='subtração') or
 (resposta !='multiplicação') or (resposta !='divisão'))
```

A resposta só pode ser uma. Então, seja qual for a resposta, ela sempre será diferente de alguma outra resposta. Isso significa que a sua verificação sempre será verdadeira, pois somente um dos termos vai ser falso e o restante será verdadeiro. Com isso você tem um loop infinito.

Outro problema: O seu `while` parece ter o objetivo de verificar se a resposta do usuário é válida, porém, você colocou os `if`s  dentro do while. Isso significa que eles vão repetir também, mesmo que a resposta esteja errada.

Tem duas formas de corrigir esse segundo problema:

Retirando os `if`s de dentro do while:

```
while resposta not in ('soma', 'subtração', 'multiplicação', 'divisão'):
    print("Digite uma operação válida")
    resposta = str(input("Qual operação você deseja usar? \n"))

if resposta == 'soma':
    ... etc ...
```

A outra forma é usar os próprios `if`s para verificar a validade da resposta:

```
resposta = str(input("Qual operação você deseja usar?\n"))
while resposta != 'sair':

    if resposta == 'soma':
        ....
    elif resposta =='subtração': 
        ....
    elif resposta =='multiplicação':
        ....
    elif resposta =='divisão':
        ....
    else:
        print("Digite uma operação válida")

    resposta = str(input("Qual operação você deseja usar? \n"))
```

Passando a leitura da resposta para o final, a condição de saída fica sendo a resposta `'sair'`.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo basta você alterar a posição do seguinte trecho de código:

```
print("Digite uma operação válida")
resposta = str(input("Qual operação você deseja usar? \n"))
```

Colocando o mesmo apos o ultimo elif:

```
elif resposta =='divisão':
    n1 = int(input("Digite o primeiro valor "))
    n2 = int(input("Digite o segundo valor "))
    resultado = n1/n2
    print("A divisão de", n1, "/", n2, "é", resultado)

print("Digite uma operação válida")
resposta = str(input("Qual operação você deseja usar? \n"))
```

No entanto seu laço é infinito uma solução não elegante seria a seguinte:

while(resposta !='Sair'):